# How to block all threads by execute critical section (within Lock) only once

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class *MyClass* which contains a static method *GetObject()*. Multiple threads are calling *GetObject()*. If *int count* is less then 3, then use old object (created in class member).

Assume Threads t4, t5, t6 enters ELSE block.

I am stuck in a ELSE condition block in which:

1. I want to create *new Object()* only once for the first thread (t4) which enters *lock()* (t5 and t6 are still blocked)
2. After unlock of first thread (t4), rest of blocked threads (t5 & t6) should return the newly created object by first thread (t4) instead of creating *new Object* per thread.

I do not want other blocked Threads to create *new Object()*.

I have also tried with [*Condition*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

I have tried below code.

```
public Class MyClass  //Singleton - persistent data class.
{
    static MyClass s_instance;   //Singleton instance
    Object myObject = new Object();    
    private int count = 0;
    private final Lock myLock = new ReentrantLock();

    public MySystem()
    {
        s_instance = this;
        System.out.println("Constructor finished");
    }    

    public static Object GetObject()
    {
        if(s_instance.count < 3)
        {
            s_instance.count++;
            System.out.println("FROM IF " + s_instance.myObject);
            return s_instance.myObject;
        }
        else
        {
            s_instance.myLock.lock();        <----- All threads blocked here
            try{
                 Thread.sleep(2000);   //Performing database operations here.      
                 System.out.println("Creating new Object");          
                 s_instance.myObject = new Object();      //Assigning new Object to Singleton class.      
            }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    //Handling exception HERE
            } finally {
                s_instance.myLock.unlock();
            }

           System.out.println("FROM ELSE " + s_instance.myObject);
        }
        return s_instance.myObject;
     }
}

Expected Output from logs:
FROM IF java.lang.Object@aa940f3   <--- Old object
FROM IF java.lang.Object@aa940f3   <--- Old object
FROM IF java.lang.Object@aa940f3   <--- Old object
Creating new Object
FROM ELSE java.lang.Object@64fed39d   <--- Thread t4 New object
FROM ELSE java.lang.Object@64fed39d   <--- Object created by Thread t4.
FROM ELSE java.lang.Object@64fed39d   <--- Object created by Thread t4.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code from your GetObject() method is not thread safe because 2 threads could evaluate the if(s_instance.count < 3) condition simultaneously, then both of them would increment s_instance.count++, potentially causing the counter to reach a value greater than 3:

```
//NOTE: this is not thread safe
if(s_instance.count < 3)
{
    s_instance.count++;
    System.out.println("FROM IF " + s_instance.myObject);
    return s_instance.myObject;
}
```

Additionally, since the problematic code block always returns from the GetObject() method, there is no need for an else statement.  To make the GetObject() method thread safe, I suggest the following changes:

```
public static Object GetObject() {
    do {
        synchronized(s_instance) {
            if(s_instance.count < 3) {
                //We can safely increment here, and the return will break us out of do/while loop
                s_instance.count++;
                System.out.println("FROM IF " + s_instance.myObject);
                return s_instance.myObject;
            }
        }

        //Now, the only way execution reaches here is if the count reached 3
        s_instance.myLock.lock();

        //Because multiple threads could reach here, we only want the first one
        //to create a new instance, all the others should loop
        if(s_instance.count == 3) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);   //Performing database operations here.      
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex) {
             //Handling exception HERE
            } 
            finally {
                //Moved the logic to finally block so even if sleep was interrupted, a new instance will be constructed
                System.out.println("Creating new Object");          
                s_instance.myObject = new Object();      //Assigning new Object to Singleton class.
                s_instance.count = 0; //don't forget to reset counter
                s_instance.myLock.unlock();
                return s_instance.myObject; //return from here to break out of do/while loop
            }
       }
       else {
           //We weren't the first thread to want a new object, so release the
           //lock and the while loop will let redo the increment logic
           s_instance.myLock.unlock();
       }
   } while(true); //Keep looping until we are successful
```

}

Comment: Thanks, That example really helped. I didn't took the all but i get the idea about the implementation.